# SQL multiple results with entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, entity

I want to merge result of two SQL select statements into one.

Here is sample :

```
// class
public class _Product
{
        public long ProductId { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class _Company
{
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        public int posotion{ get; set; }
}


// C# entity
void runQyery()
{
     string MultiQuery = "select ProductId, Description from product;"+
                         " select CompanyId, posotion from Company;";

     _Product objPro = new _Product();
     _Company objCom = new _Company();

     // Is this right? What should I do now?
     var result = _entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(MultiQuery);

     objPro = ...
     objCom = ...
}
```

How can I finish my code? Is there any way to read some select on one trying?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: I don't understand this. Are you trying to populate two collections with a single query? You should first populate your Products, then with a second database call populate the Company collection.

Comment: @SeanLange answer of your question is "Yes". But I think there is a way to get both query on one

Comment: Why can't you create a View with UNION of these two select and call that VIEW in `ExecuteSqlCommand`? Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: I don't think you can do this quite like this. And more importantly why are you trying to populate two distinct types of objects with one statement? This kind of goes against the whole concept of separation.

Comment: @Vijai we can't use that at all, the result of each select is different, how you should use that, impossible

Comment: @SeanLange it's just a sample, on real project I have 7-10 select on one function . I must to call all of them by one query , maybe I must to use store produce

Comment: Until the data types of each columns in the select statement are same you can use UNION for multiple select statements.

Comment: In your case trying to get company and product in the same query is not a good idea. You can either JOIN company and product to get relevant information or get it separately.

Comment: Just curious, your tag have `entity`, which means you are using `entity framework`.  If that is the case, IMO, populate table by table can keep the meta data of them, and let EF to handle the `constraint`, it will be easier for maintenance and coding afterward

Comment: Who cares how many object collections you have? The code to retrieve them from the database should be isolated to that object. You need to think about coupling here. What you are trying to do is called tight coupling and is what you want to avoid. You need loose coupling so that all your objects can be independent. Doing this all in one step is going to be a nightmare to maintain in the long run.